# A continuous complex function such that $f(\mathbb{S}^{1})\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ verify $\left|\int_{S^{1}}f(z)dz\right| \leq 4\max_{x\in S^{1}}|f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have the following problem:

Let f a continuous function such that $f(\mathbb{S}^{1})\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, prove that
\begin{equation*}
    \left|\int_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}f(z)dz\right| \leq 4\max_{x\in\mathbb{S}^{1}}|f(z)|
\end{equation*}

What i try is: Let $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}f(z)dz = Re^{i\theta} \in\mathbb{C}$, note that
\begin{equation}
    R = \left|\int_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}f(z)dz\right|
\end{equation}

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
            R
            & = &   e^{-i\theta}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}f(z)dz\\
            & = &   \int_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}e^{-i\theta}f(z)dz\\
            & = &   \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}f(e^{it})ie^{it}dt\\
            & = &   \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})ie^{i(t-\theta)}dt\\
            & = & \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})[i(\cos(t-\theta)+i\sin(t-\theta)]dt\\
            & = &   \text{Re}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})[(i\cos(t-\theta)-\sin(t-\theta)]dt\\
            & = &   \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})\sin(\theta-t)dt\\
        \end{eqnarray*}
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
        R
        & =  &  \left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it}\sin(\theta-t)dt\right|\\
        &\leq&  \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(e^{it}|\cdot|\sin(\theta-t)|dt\\
        &\leq&  \max_{z\in\mathbb{S}^{1}}|f(z)|\cdot\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin(\theta-t)|dt\\
        & =  &  4\max_{z\in\mathbb{S}^{1}}|f(z)|
    \end{eqnarray*}
concluding the desired. I wanted to know if there is an alternative way to do this demonstration, either with complex variable tools, or analysis in general.

Also as a comment, this type of properties is interesting because we have
\begin{equation*}
        \left|\int_{\mathbb{S}^{1}} f(z)dz\right| \leq\text{L}(\mathbb{S}^{1})\cdot\max_{z\in\mathbb{S}^{1}}|f(z)|=2\pi\cdot\max_{z\in\mathbb{S}^{1}}|f(z)|
    \end{equation*}
and $2\pi\sim6.28>4$, in summary, we obtain an improvement of the dimension that gives us the length of the curve.

Comment: Isn't this just the Estimation Theorem with extra steps?

Comment: This looks like a nice straight-forward proof.

Comment: I doubt that tools from complex analysis can be applied here, because $f$ is “only” continuous. But I may be wrong of course.